# When compiling a project with SignalR I have to do a iisreset

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have an n-tier application which I have added SignalR functionality to. When I now compile my business layer I have to do a iisreset before the website can load again. It simply just keeps loading, and doesn't get anywhere. Even a kill on the w3wp process doesn't help this out.

I have tried and removed SignalR and then it works fine when compiling the backend. My guess is that a connection is made from SignalR to the server, and it is broken when the backend is compiled, which haults the site from doing a complete load.

Anything I might be able to do about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you developing on windows 7? If you are then don't as it only allows 10 concurrent connections. Use IIS express instead.

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: This boggles me, why is the lighter IIS version, better than the regular IIS for e.g. SignalR?

Comment: Didn't you read the answer? IIS on Windows 7 a **client** OS only allows 10 concurrent connections. If you use IIS express (which is for development purposes only) or IIS 7.x on Windows Server, there's no restriction.

Comment: I am sorry I misunderstood you, I thought you were talking about the default built in server in VS. Thanks for your help.